# How can I cause moving text to gradually disappear and reappear rather than teleporting at the end of an animation?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have some right to left scrolling text that teleports back to the origin at the end of the animation, while I am more so looking for it to disappear out of and appear into the margin.

```css
.example1 {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.example1 h3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  animation: example1 10s linear infinite;te  
}

@keyframes example1 {
  from {
    margin-left: 60%;
    width: 300%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 35%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
  <h3>text</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need your CSS animation to only run once, you have to set the [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) property to `1` (in fact, to not set it at all, as `1` is its default value).

You're currently setting it to `infinite`, using the `animation` shorthand, which sets multiple animation properties in one single declaration. Just remove `infinte` from that line. You should also remove the `te` following that declaration, which is invalid CSS.

To have your animation animate multiple properties, you can add as many animatable properties to your keyframes and they will animate accordingly. In your case, adding a `50%` keyframe with `opacity:1` and adding `opacity:0` to the `to` keyframe will make your element fade from `1` to `0` starting at half of the animation until its end.

Using [`animation-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function), particularly with [timing functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function#Timing_functions) (a.k.a. as easings), allows adding acceleration and deceleration to animations, making them look more "natural", especially when used on movement animations.

Another handy property of CSS animations is the [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode). It allows setting the animated properties to the values they have been animated to, when the animation ends (as opposed to being reset to any applying CSS). This avoids the "jump" whenever you have animated a property to a different value that what normally applies to it.

Last note, on performance: to make sure your animations run smoothly on any device, you should only animate properties which do not trigger repaints on subsequent elements. In fact, you should strive to ever animate only 2 properties: `transform` and `opacity`. In your case, rather than animating `margin-left`, which moves your element around and triggers repaint on subsequent elements in DOM, you should never actually move it and use `transform` to paint it at different positions.

Here's an example (not sure if this is what you asked for, but you can play around with it some more):

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #212121;
}
.example1 h3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  animation: example1 5s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1) forwards;
}

@keyframes example1 {
  from{
    transform: translateX(107%);
  }
  38% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  42% {    
    transform: translateX(35%);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(35%);
  }
  62% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
  <h3>text</h3>
</div>
```

If, on the contrary, you want your animation looping but want to simply create a smooth transition between end and start, the golden rule is in both `from` and `to` keyframes the animated properties have to have the same values (because default value of `transform:translateX()` is `0` and of `opacity` is `1`, I don't need to set them in `from` - that's the starting point):

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #212121;
}
.example1 h3 {
  color: white;
  text-align:right;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  animation: example1 5s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1) infinite;
}

@keyframes example1 {
  38% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  42% {    
    transform: translateX(-60%);
  }
  58% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-60%);
  }
  62% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
  <h3>text</h3>
</div>
```

For more on animation syntax and examples, I recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations), a well curated documentation library, joint effort of Mozilla, Google, Microsoft and many, many others. Arguably, its most useful feature is linking, in the **Specifications** section, at the bottom, currently applying standards for the respective property or method, so you don't have to waste time tracking them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use more keyframes percentage to control better your animation in stead of using just two keyframes (from/to).

Below a quick example:

```css
.example1 {
 height: 50px;  
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.example1 h3 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 color: white;
 line-height: 50px;
 animation: example1 10s linear infinite;te
}
@keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    margin-left: 60%;
    width: 300%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 35%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
<h3>text</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating the `margin-left` style you should animate the `left` style, example:

```css
 .example1 {
 height: 50px;
 width: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.example1 h3 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 line-height: 50px;
 animation: example1 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes example1 {
  from {
    left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    left: -10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
<h3>text</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it causes it to start from the very edges of the screen. I want it to start at the margins I selected before, merely with a different style. I've seen it done before and don't know how to go about it.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can decrease its travel width by reducing the width of its parent container.

Comment: This just causes it to become the same as it were with margin-left

Comment: Here is an example: https://gyazo.com/6d6f651fe574a8a2e052e98763b3bdde

Comment: My snippet behaves exactly like that example. There is no jumping text. The text appears from one side, scrolls, and then disappears on the other side. I don't understand what more do you want.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little slow. This ended up working, however when I have multiple words that I'm trying to animate, the others end up bugging at the start of the animation and popping into existence rather than slowly appearing from the right. Example: https://i.gyazo.com/9c08d00983eff3cf622a7904b3c79262.mp4